# ¿Cómo Kubelet realmente trabaja?

Tags: docker, cloud, kubernetes

Quisiera saber como realmente Kubelet trabaja. Tengo un mini cluster de dos nodos y un master. He desplegado solo 1 Pod que tiene 2 contenedores

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-app
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nextcloud
    image: nextcloud:apache
    env:
    - name: MYSQL_HOST
      value: "db"
  - name: database
    image: mariadb
    env:
    - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
      value: "123456"
    - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
      value: "nextcloud"
    - name: MYSQL_USER
      value: "nextcloud"
    - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
      value: "123456"
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
    - containerPort: 3306
```

Dicho Pod se despliegue en mi Nodo2

```
kubectl describe pod my-app |grep Node
Node: n2.example.com/192.168.56.102
Node-Selectors:  <none>
```

Si detengo mi servicio Kubelet en mi Nodo 2, o incluso apago la máquina virtual de mi Nodo 2, el Master no es capaz de conmutar el despliegue de mi aplicación my-app al siguiente nodo Nodo3. Lo dejé un buen rato y esto no sucede. Mi pregunta es: ¿ Que debo hacer para que el Master se entere que un Pod esta caido e inmediatamente despliegue la aplicación en el siguiente Nodo disponible?, ¿Existe algún tiempo por defecto o configurable para que el Master conmute el despliegue de dicha aplicación al siguiente Nodo?

Gracias de antemano,

Answer (score 1):

como estás?. Cuando creas un deployment el replicaset se genera automáticamente. El número de replicas se lo indicas.

```html
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-v1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-v1
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-v1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello
        image: gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent        
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "64Mi"
            cpu: "200m"
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
```

Por último, ejecuta en el namespace que estas parado un Kubectl get all y vas a ver creado el replicaset. Si queres ver como lo crea podes usar kubectl describe replicaset [Nombre]. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas un [ReplicationController](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicationcontroller/) o un mejor aún [ReplicaSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/)

Este un ejemplod que yo tengo:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  name: owncloud
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: owncloud
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: owncloud
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: owncloud
        image: owncloud:10.0.10
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
```

El ReplicaSet se encarga de que siempre haya el número de pods que menciones en `replicas`